# Extract the generating curves from a Graphics3D returned from RevolutionPlot3D

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

I have a plot

```
g = RevolutionPlot3D[{Sin[t], t}, {t, 0, π}, {θ, -π, π + 3 π/4}];
```

Is it possible to extract the generatrices (generating curves) from `g`?

Sometimes, I want to concentrate on plotting the surface in different ways, and what I need is the all the generating curves. Can I obtain these curves from `g`?.

---

For example, this is what I need (the data could be plot by `Line /@ curves` and could be exported elsewhere).

```
curves = Table[RotationMatrix[θ, {0, 0, 1}]. {Sin[t], 0, t},
               {θ, 0, 2π, .3}, {t, 0, π, .3}];
```

The example result, `curves`, is what I want, but I obtain that by re-think about generating method and `{Sin[t], 0, t}`. Seems defining `g` was a waste of time.

But in the plot of `g`, such lines/meshes are really shown by *Mathematica*, so I would like to extract them.

Comment: Pardon me, but what is a "mother line" in this context?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard A equivalent of "generatrix", I believe. "Generatrix" is called 母(mother)线(line) in Chinese.

Comment: @xzczd okay, so what is a *generatrix*?  The [usual resources](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/search/?q=generatrix) come up empty.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Well, I didn't expect it's so hard to find a detailed explanation for this word……Dictionaries (for example, this: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/generatrix) do include it though. This word can be found in the wiki page of [cone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cone_(geometry)).

Comment: I *think* the OP is looking to get the normal from `Z` to the surface from an existing graphics object, as in parsing the samples at `[[1,1]]` of the graphics object. Not sure why one would do that, except if someone passed along a notebook with a plot without the plotting commands used to generate it.

Comment: Imo OP wants to extract mesh, especially vertical part, which is {Sin[z],0,0} But the latter explanation about generating different surfaces is not clear to me.

Comment: @SEuser2013 Hello :) so what, more than in the example, do you want?

Comment: @Kuba The example result `curves` is what I want, but I obtain that by re-think about generating method and `{Sin[t],0,t}`. Seems the step `g` is useless.

Comment: @SEuser2013 ok, so what do you need, only the plot of those curves, or approximate coordinates, or parametric formula?

Comment: @Kuba `approximate coordinates` or parametric formula(could generate the data)

Comment: @xzczd Does for example "generating function" follows the same name convention in Chinese? (just curiosity)

Comment: @belisarius You got it! It's called "母函数" in Chinese. (There exists a more straight translation "生成函数" though.)

Comment: @xzczd Ha! "Learning Chinese by induction" :)

Answer (score 7):

You can see them with:

```
g2 = RevolutionPlot3D[{Sin[t], t}, {t, 0, π}, {θ, -π, π + 3 π/4}, 
                       PlotStyle -> None, Mesh -> {0, 10}, BoundaryStyle -> None]
```

[image]

And since you want coordinates aswell, then:

```
Cases[ Normal@g2, _Line, \[Infinity]]
```

> ```
> {Line[{<<185>>}], Line[{<<85>>}], Line[{<<85>>}], Line[{<<85>>}], 
>  Line[{<<85>>}], Line[{<<73>>}], Line[{<<73>>}], Line[{<<73>>}], 
>  Line[{<<73>>}], Line[{<<73>>}], <<1>>}
> ```

Comment: nice! I think this is what I need, thanks.

Comment: But I should check the order of the lines. Let me see.

Comment: `Cases[Normal@g2, _Line, \[Infinity]]` do you know the sort method used in this result, I found one thing is that `Cases[Normal@g2, _Line, \[Infinity]][[1]]` looks like two lines(joined).

Comment: @SEuser2013 p.s it is boundary line so just add `BoundaryStyle->None` to `g2`.

Comment: well, Let's set `mesh->{0,100}`. can we let this rotate smoothly from `[0,2Pi]`·  
`Manipulate[Graphics3D[Cases[Normal@g2,_Line,\[Infinity]][[x]],PlotRange->5],{x,1,100,1}]`

Comment: @SEuser2013 `Manipulate[
 RevolutionPlot3D[{Sin[t], t}, {t, 0, \[Pi]}, {\[Theta], 0, 2 Pi}, 
  PlotStyle -> None, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {0, Pi}}, 
  Mesh -> {0, {\[Theta]m}}, BoundaryStyle -> None, MeshStyle -> Thick]
 ,
 {{\[Theta]m, Pi}, 0, 2 Pi, .01}]` ?